# How do I implement a list comprehension using map and filter?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Both `map` and `filter` can be implemented using list comprehension:

```
map f xs    = [f x | x <- xs]
filter p xs = [x | x <- xs, p x]
```

I'd like to show that the converse holds as well using the following example:

```
[expr | p <- s]
```

I've got so far:

```
map (\p -> expr) s
```

But this works only when pattern matching with `p` succeeds on all elements of `s`. In a way, I first want to filter `s` using a pattern matching on `p`. Naturally, I tried looking into this question but I haven't been able to find a solution which didn't use list comprehension or LambdaCase.

Comment: `[expr | p <- s]` is the same as `map (\p -> expr) s`. Not putting this as an answer though since I'm not entirely sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Again, this is only true when ```p``` actually succeeds on all elements of ```s``` in pattern matching.

Comment: For example: ```[2*x | (x,2) <- [(1,2), (3,4)]]``` would fail.

Comment: I didn't know it would do that - I thought it would fail with an exception! Then again, I don't use comprehensions very often, so I'm not surprised I got this wrong.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, you could use [`mapMaybe`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.23/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) from `Data.Maybe` to combine filtering and mapping in one step. e.g. your example is `mapMaybe (\val -> case val of { (x, 2) -> Just (2*x) ; _ -> Nothing) [(1,2), (3,4)]

Comment: @bradrn strictly speaking they are not the same, since the list comprehension silently ignores a pattern match failure. The Report gives [desugaring rules for list comprehensions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11).

Comment: I believe it is equivalent to `let { ok p = [expr]; ok _ = [] } in concatMap ok s`.

Comment: To answer the question, you can't show this because it is not true: `\xs -> [f x | x <- xs, p x] =/= map f . filter p`. See the above discussion about pattern matching failures. However, I think you can show something weaker: in all cases where `map f . filter p` returns a value, it is the same as the value returned by the list comprehension.

Comment: Just realised I forgot a closing backtick and braces in my code above - it should be `mapMaybe (\val -> case val of { (x, 2) -> Just (2*x) ; _ -> Nothing } ) [(1,2), (3,4)]`

Comment: Alternatively, if the pattern is _irrefutable_ then the behavior is equivalent, since the pattern cannot fail to match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this works only when pattern matching with `p` succeeds on all elements of `s`.

Indeed: the pattern matching behaviour you describe cannot, in general, be achieved with `map` and `filter` alone. Expressing comprehensions in such terms only works well in the simpler case of comprehensions with a single generator and patterns that won't fail. Rather, list comprehensions [are specified in the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) in terms of `concatMap`. In particular, the clause about generators covers the possibility of pattern match failure:

```
--This is pseudo-Haskell; see the Report for the fine print.
[  e | p <- l,  Q ] = let ok p = [  e | Q ]
                          ok _ = []
                          in concatMap ok l
```

The handling of match failures corresponds to what `fail` does in the desugaring of list monad do-blocks.

Comment: Perhaps we could helpfully restrict the problem to list comprehensions whose patterns are irrefutable, as SPJ and Wadler do in [_Comprehensive Comprehensions_](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/list-comp.pdf).

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Perhaps, though as far as the OP's goal is concerned we would also have to exclude comprehensions with multiple generators.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you cannot do pattern matching on a lambda without either using \x -> case x of... (or LambdaCase to shorten it); your example:

```hs
[2*x | (x,2) <- [(1,2), (3,4)]]
```

would have to be implemented as:

```hs
map (\(x,_) -> 2*x) $ filter (\(_,y) -> y == 2) [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Or, using LambdaCase:

```hs
map (\(x,_) -> 2*x) $ filter (\case (_,2) -> True; _ -> False) [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Also, for a point-free version:

```hs
map ((2*) . fst) $ filter ((==2) . snd) [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

Comment: I'm interested in having a "general approach" for ```[expr | p <- s]```. Is there a way to express the ```filter``` more generally? More precise, could you have it in this form:
```map (\p -> expr) $ filter (???) s```

Comment: @Ketho I don't believe you can do this - see [ReinHenrichs's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369537/how-do-i-implement-a-list-comprehension-using-map-and-filter?noredirect=1#comment99342124_56369537) on your question

Comment: If you mean, "what if I don't want to filter, I want to map all the elements in the list", you can either omit the filter and just do map, or filter by a function that always returns True: ```map (\p -> expr) $ filter (\p -> True) s```